# Higgs U(1) charge and the isospin operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electroweak, isospin-symmetry

So if the higgs field $h=(h^+,h^0)$ is at its vev (up to a gauge choice) with $\langle h\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(0,v)$, then in turn you can show

$$I_{1}\langle h\rangle=\frac{\sigma_1}{2}\langle h\rangle  = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(v,0)\neq 0$$

$$I_{2}\langle h\rangle=\frac{\sigma_2}{2}\langle h\rangle  = -\frac{i}{2\sqrt{2}}(v,0)\neq 0$$

$$I_{3}\langle h\rangle=\frac{\sigma_3}{2}\langle h\rangle  = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(0,v)\neq 0$$

and

$$Y\langle h\rangle=\langle h\rangle  \neq 0$$

So that one gets that $Q\langle h\rangle=(I_3 + Y/2)\langle h\rangle =0$ and hence the vacuum is invariant under $U(1)_{Q}$ with $Q=(I_3 + Y/2)$.

But what about for complex linear combinations of the operators? are there any ways to make sense of this? For example the fact that $(I_1 -i\cdot I_2)\langle h\rangle =0$, so technically $e^{i(I_{1}-i\cdot I_{2})}\langle h\rangle=\langle h\rangle$ and hence the higgs vacuum is invariant under this $U(1)_{I_{-}}$ with $I_{-}=I_{1}-i\cdot I_{2}$?

I guess there is a reason this lowering weak isospin operator is not a useful group to consider? Thanks

Comment: Your exponential is not a unitary matrix, so it's not a U(1). It's not a subgroup of weak isospin.

Comment: Of course! thank you for clearing up my confusion!